# Ray marching on non-enclosed SDF

Tags: graphics, rendering, raycasting, raymarching

I am trying to implement ray marching rendering of some SDF and these SDFs represented interfaces and top surface of a structure with material regions distributed between adjacent SDF represented surfaces. In my case, new material regions are introduced one after another, the requirement is to visualise separate material region incrementally as new regions are introduced.
Since my application seeks speed and memory efficiency, I am trying to using ray-marching instead of converting the SDF to mesh then rendering based on polygon mesh. The problem is that the SDF I got has no SDF information for four sidewalls.
Is there any way I can construct the SDF for each interface  together with its boundary faces then apply ray-marching rendering or is there any other better way to do this?

[case description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgNyC.png)

I tried to figure out a way to construct a closed SDF with four sidewalls based on the interface or top surface SDFs and could not got a clue, and using Manhattan distance seems hinders the possibility of using ray marching for rendering, since the marching step based on Manhattan distance will cross the geometry to be rendered.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYUyb.png)

Is it feasible to using ray-marching on Manhattan SDF? If so,Is there any way I can construct the SDF for each interface together with its boundary faces then apply ray-marching rendering or is there any other better way to do this?